# Creating arraylist of array

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to create an Arraylist which has array of Strings at each index. I have used following code:

```
ArrayList<String[]> deliveryTimes = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] str = new String[times.size()];//times is an Arraylist of string
for(int i=0; i<times.size();i++){
    str[i] = times.get(i);
}
deliveryTimes.add(str);
```

With above code all the elements of str array are added at different index in deliveryTimes arraylist. But I want to add str as array at a index. So it should be like following:

```
[["a","b","c"],["aa","bb","cc"],["aaa","bbb","ccc"]]
```

But it is like:

```
["a","b","c","aa","bb","cc","aaa","bbb","ccc"]
```

Comment: Do you have multiple ´times´ arrays or single and you need to split it evenly?

Comment: do you add "a" to "ccc" in that single for loop?

Comment: What is your times array?

Answer (score 2):

```
....
String[] first = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
String[] second = new String[]{"aa", "bb", "cc"};
String[] third = new String[]{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};

addArrays(first, second, third);

...

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> addArrays(String[]... strings) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allTimes = new ArrayList<>(strings.length);

    for (String[] array : strings) {
        allTimes.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array)));
    }

    return allTimes;
}
```

allTimes contains: [[a, b, c], [aa, bb, cc], [aaa, bbb, ccc]]

Answer (score 0):

Your `deliveryTimes` list only contains one `String[]`. Add multiple `String[]` to `deliveryTimes` list.

```
ArrayList<String[]> deliveryTimes = new ArrayList<String[]>();

String[] one = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
String[] two = new String[]{"aa", "bb", "cc"};
String[] three = new String[]{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};

deliveryTimes.add(one);
deliveryTimes.add(two);
deliveryTimes.add(three);

for (String[] str : deliveryTimes) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
}
```

**Output**

> [a, b, c]
>
> [aa, bb, cc]
>
> [aaa, bbb, ccc]

You need to split your times list and add them to deliveryTimes List separately.